# Pulling information from a cell in a .csv file into a variable in Excel using vba

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on a vba macro for an excel sheet and I'm not sure how to go about doing one of my functions. I have a private sub in the macro that is used to get the path of a .csv file (say C:/files/file.csv stored as variable 'csvfile').

What I need to do at this point is automatically pull information from that csv file according to a certain formula and save it as a variable:

```
=COUNTIFS(F2:F10000,"=medium",Z2:Z10000,"=Open")
```

So in summary, in a macro in spreadsheet Main.xlsx, I need to run the above formula on the file whose path is stored in variable csvfile, and save the returned number as a variable within the macro so I can make use of that number in my macro.

I'll need to do this nine times actually with the formula slightly different each time, but once I have the single variable worked out I think I'll be able to modify it to produce all the results I need.

Thanks

Comment: There's at least two paths you could take. 1) Open the .csv as a textstream and parse it for the information you want all in VBA, or 2) Open the .csv to a worksheet, use the worksheet functions (through VBA) to find what you want, then delete the worksheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of one way to do it:

```
Sub OpenAndCount()
    Dim sFile As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cnt As Long
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range


    sFile = "c:\files\file.csv"
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(sFile)
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
    Set rng1 = ws.Range("F2:F100000")
    Set rng2 = ws.Range("Z2:Z100000")

    cnt = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(rng1, "=medium*", rng2, "=open")

    Debug.Print cnt
    wb.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, this does appear to work for what I need. Now I just need to convert it to do what I actually require, which I think will be doable using this format.